# Enable/disable dialog button on item click

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I have designed an alert dialog which contains list view. I want to enable the positive button of dialog only when an item is clicked else keep it disabled. I am unable to enable the button after click. Find my code below:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
View view = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_list, null);

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Select any action");
alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);
alertDialogBuilder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);

actionLV = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.action_list);
actionLV.setAdapter(new ActionListAdapter(actionAL,getActivity()));

alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

        // Write your code here to invoke YES event
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on Cancel",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {  

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),LogItActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ACTION_NAME", ActionListAdapter.checkedActionName);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});

AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            if(ActionListAdapter.checkedActionName != null){
                done.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });
alertDialog.show();

done = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
done.setEnabled(false);
if(ActionListAdapter.checkedActionName!= null){
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Someone please guide me.

Comment: where is your listview item click listener.?

Comment: I have enabled the button in adapter class inside click listener. Its working

Answer (score 0):

int listItem;

1. default setenabled false.
2. setonitemclicklistner on listview;
3. on item click listItem=position and change coloe of selected item and set enabled true

Comment: I have set onClickListener inside adapter because my list item has one invisible view. onClick I have made that view visible. Probably I cannot do the same if I set onItemClickListener on listview.

Comment: what is the issue button is not getting disabled ?

Comment: button is disabled. Unable to enable it.

Comment: Inside adapter, onClick of view, I have enabled the button. Now its working.

Comment: you can do the same with onitemclicklistner .. good its working fine